# Is it possible to play/pause an .html object?

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I've been trying to add play/pause functionality to my html object using javascript but the buttons don't seem to work and I don't find any errors in the console.

```html
<object data="dice.html" width="550px" height="400px" id="Player" style="visibility: visible;">
  <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
  <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
</object>
<p>
  <button id="play1">Play</button>
  <button id="play2">Pause</button>
</p>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
  document.getElementById('play1').onClick = function() {
    document.getElementById('Player').Play();
  }
  document.getElementById('play2').onClick = function() {
    document.getElementById('Player').Stop();
  }
</script>
```

I tried looking for solutions online and most of them discuss .swf file types only. Is it possible to play/pause an .html object? The .html file was published using Flash.

Answer (score 1):

Actually when you export your flash project into an html file, it creates an html file that already embeds the `swf`.

So I think that your best bet to get control via javascript on it would be to **directly embed the swf into your** `object` **tag**.

Now, even if in your case **it seems really not appropriated**,
to access an html file embedded in an `object`, you should use the [`contentDocument`property](http://help.dottoro.com/ljlwjldb.php).

```
document.querySelector("object").contentDocument.getElementById("external_element").doStuff()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use something such as [SWFobject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed the swf itself into your webpage.

After that's done you should be able to do what you wish with the resulting reference to the actual swf object. You may need to use ExternalInterface to do what you want.

Comment: The problem is I have more than one scene in my flash file, so that  doesn't merge all the scenes into one .swf. I'll be left with 6 swf  files and there's no way I can merge them using flash.